# how can i use id of option in selectlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

my code is:
html:

```
  <select id="select" onclick="getValue()">
         <option id="profile-pic">profile pic</option>
         <option id="product-image">product image</option>
    </select>
    <div id="radio-button">
      <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
      male
      </label>
   <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
      female
   </label>
 </div>
 <div id="dropdown">
   <select id="select">
     <option>profile pic</option>
     <option>product image</option>
   </select>
   <select id="select">
     <option>profile pic</option>
     <option>product image</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $("div#dropdown").hide();
         $("div#radio-button").hide();

    });




    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#select").change(function(){

    $("div#dropdown").hide();
     $("div#radio-button").show();
  });
$("#select").click(function(){

    $("div#dropdown").show();
     $("div#radio-button").hide();
  });

});
```

I want to use id of option in selectlist.
I have two option in select(1:profile-pic, 2:product-image) .
what i want:
when i clicked on profile pic it shows two radio button.
and if I select product image it shows two dropdown.

Comment: dont use your id name twice..make another id for the other select

Comment: k that was my mistake. but can you give me answer of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure to use an ID only once per page. An ID is a UNIQUE identifier of some element. I guess that "select" or "dropdown" aren't really unique page elements, so think of better names, for example "profile_picture_select" and "product_image_select".

Also, don't use inline javascript (onclick="getValue()").

EXAMPLE

HTML

```
<select id="function_select">
    <option>profile_picture_select</option>
    <option>product_image_select</option>
</select>

<div id="profile_picture_select">profile_picture_select</div>
<div id="product_image_select">product_image_select</div>
```

JavaScript (jQuery) (use indentation)

```
$(function () {                          // Same as $(document).ready().
    $("#profile_picture_select").hide(); // By ID, so no element needed.
    $("#product_image_select").hide();

    // Just one document ready function.

    $("#function_select").change(function () {
        switch ($(this).val()) {
            case "profile_picture_select":
                $("#profile_picture_select").show();
                $("#product_image_select").hide();
                break;
            case "product_image_select":
                $("#profile_picture_select").hide();
                $("#product_image_select").show();
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

Check the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c3Ehb/

Comment: Please read my answer properly. Start with doing some renaming.

Answer (score 0):

```
JQuery

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dropdown").hide();
    $("#radio-button").hide();

    $("#select").change(function () {
        if($("#select option:selected").text() == 'profile pic')
        {
            $("#dropdown").hide();
            $("#radio-button").show();
        }
        if($("#select option:selected").text() == 'product image')
        {
            $("#dropdown").show();
            $("#radio-button").hide();
        }
    });
});

HTML

<select id="select">
    <option>profile pic</option>
    <option>product image</option>
</select>
<div id="radio-button">
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
        male
    </label>
   <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
      female
   </label>
 </div>
 <div id="dropdown">
   <select id="select">
     <option>profile pic</option>
     <option>product image</option>
   </select>
   <select id="select">
     <option>profile pic</option>
     <option>product image</option>
   </select>
</div>
```